# MySQL CASE Statement Pivot issue

Tags: mysql

Please Suggest for converting table 1 to table2..

```
Actual Result:  
      User_id type   created_at
        1        1     2015-02-01
        1        2     2015-03-10
        1        3     2015-04-22 



Expected Result:

    user_id, type1_date, type2_date, type3_date
```

Query:

```
select user_id, 
       case when type=1 then created_at end as Type1,
       case when type=2 then created_at end as Type2,
       case when type=3 then created_at end as Type3 
from t1
```

Comment: Did you try something ?

Comment: yeah i added case for each type but its gives 3 rows but m looking for in 1 row

Comment: @jacob53: How many types will be there in your table?

Comment: select user_id, case when type=1 then created_at end as Type1,case when type=2 then created_at end as Type2,case when type=3 then created_at end as Type3 from t1

Answer (score 1):

**Problem in your query:**

```
select user_id, 
       case when type=1 then created_at end as Type1,
       case when type=2 then created_at end as Type2,
       case when type=3 then created_at end as Type3 
from t1
```

You haven't used the aggregate function `MAX()`. So the query will not eliminate the fields with `NULL` values.

**Solution:**

Use `MAX()` and `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT user_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN type=1 THEN created_at END) AS type1_date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN type=2 THEN created_at END) AS type2_date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN type=3 THEN created_at END) AS type3_date
FROM t1
GROUP BY user_id
```

This is an alternative for `pivot` if the type column values are limitied:

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT User_id,
     MAX(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN created_at END) AS type1_date,
     MAX(CASE WHEN type = 2 THEN created_at END) AS type2_date,
     MAX(CASE WHEN type = 3 THEN created_at END) AS type3_date
FROM {your_table}
GROUP BY User_id
```